# Substrate Blockchain Explorers

Tags: cross-chain-explorers, explorer

What are the blockchain explorers compatible with substrate based blockchains?

I am aware of polkatdotjs and subscan. Is there any other solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [awesome-substrate](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/awesome-substrate). You could search `explorer` on that page. For any other requirements, you could always search here first.

You missed these:

- https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-tools-index#block-explorers

  - https://dotscanner.com/?utm_source=polkadot_wiki
- https://explorer.polkascan.io
- https://polkaholic.io/#chains